# What is the efficient data structure to store firebase notification token?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, push-notification, google-cloud-functions

My app is using Firebase real-time database as backend. Like other social networking apps, my app also has groups which can be subscribed by users for getting future events push-notification. Let's say user_1 has subscribed to more then one group (the number of the subscribed group maybe 20, 30 etc). I am using Firebase cloud functions to send push notification to the subscribers of the group when the group organizes new events. To send the notification, the Firebase cloud function first retrieves all the tokens of the subscribers from the specified 'GroupSubscriberTokens' node as shown in the figure. But Since when a user reinstalls the app the notification token changes so for that particular user does not get any notification. Now how to override the new notification token of the user to all the subscribedGroupTokens nodes using any cloud functions or if possible then from client side? If the number of the subscribed group is more then it will be difficult to override at all the nodes even from the server side using cloud function. Is there any other way to structure the firebase data so that the subscriber tokens will be retrieved by cloud function from only one place and send the notification?

[image]